# Action link parameter everywhere. How to stop it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am passing a parameter to the action method in this way:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Weddings", "Portfolio", new { param="Wedding" })
```

When the page opens, I have...param="Wedding#somenumber on every link on the page. 
How do I prevents links from grabbing this parameter?

Cheers,
Leo.

Comment: What do you mean with _"on every link on the page"_? The param will only be added to actionlinks you add it to.

Comment: The links aren't `grabbing the parameter` as much as you are using an method that injects them.  If they are a eyesore, maybe you can create a route that expects them so they blend in a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There's no way to pass the parameter via a link without appending it to the URL string.

Your only other option would be to use a form with the POST method and place the parameter in a hidden input.